# Subtracting data frames using Spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My first data frame (df1) looks like -

```
id      city_code       area_code
1          20             30
2          33             88
3          43             09
4          02             72
5          12             19
```

2nd data frame (df2)

```
id         cash           age
1          200             30
2          338             28
3          436             49
6          023             72
```

I want result looks like -

```
id      city_code       area_code
3          43             09
4          02             72
5          12             19
```

I have done -

```
df3 = df1.select('id','city_code','area_code').subtract(df2.select('id','cash','age'))

df3.show()
```

But not working

Comment: is the requirement proper?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left_anti` join to filter out rows with same `id` in both dfs

```
 df1.join(df2, 'id', "left_anti").show()
```

returns:

```
+---+---------+---------+
| id|city_code|area_code|
+---+---------+---------+
|  4|       02|       72|
|  5|       12|       19|
+---+---------+---------+
```

You can read more about `left_semi` and `left_anti` joins here: https://medium.com/datamindedbe/little-known-spark-dataframe-join-types-cc524ea39fd5